# How to indicate EGLFS plugin location for GUI Qt 5.6 application running on Raspberry?

Tags: qt, cross-compiling, qt5.6

I've been using Qt library for several years, and recently tried it on Raspberry (Qt 5.6.0) for demonstration purposes and stuck on following item:

a) there was no problem in configuring/making library on host machine and following deployment to RPi

b) the console applications works well on RPi

c) the GUI application tells next on start (absense of EGLFS plugin):

root@rpi:/home/pi# ./testpi2
This application failed to start because it could not find or load the Qt platform plugin "eglfs"
in "".

Available platform plugins are: eglfs, linuxfb, minimal, minimalegl, offscreen.

d) I checked that plugins are located in folder where "Qt" placed (in my case  /usr/local/qt5pi/plugins/platforms), so plugins have been built and deployed)

e) I tried: export QT_PLUGIN_DIR=/usr/local/qt5pi/plugins

as well as:  export QT_PLUGIN_DIR=/usr/local/qt5pi/plugins/platforms

but it didn't help.

Can you guess me in following steps ?

Comment: How your Qt is built, dinamically or statically? Read this http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt-conf.html

Comment: Thanks, Lazar.  I've built it dynamically.  
Configure parameters were:

./configure -opengl es2 -device linux-rasp-pi-g++ -device-option CROSS_COMPILE=~/opt/gcc-4.7-linaro-rpi-gnueabihf/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf- -sysroot /mnt/rasp-pi-rootfs -opensource -confirm-license -optimized-qmake -reduce-exports -release -make libs -prefix /usr/local/qt5pi -hostprefix /usr/local/qt5pi -v

Comment: Create qt.conf file beside your executable and point to platforms by writing this to your qt.conf file: [PATHS]Plugins=platforms .Be sure that your folder platforms is in the same directory as your executable.